# Does [(NgModel)] update behavior subject?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Consider the following scenario, also available here https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-4-observables-playground :

**Question**

When I modify the input field, the value of `u1` and `u3` changes. Since `[(NgModel)]` is entangled with `u1`, I expected `u1` and `u3` to be modified in memory as soon as I typed a new value, but only instantaneous read for `u1`  not `u3`.

What am I missing?

**Question Edit 1**

I expected : `[(ngModel)]="u1.username"` to change its value because the two-way data binding, but not `u3` since does not have any NgModel `<p>u3: {{u3.username}}</p>`

**Scenario**

home.page.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable, BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/from';
import {UserService} from '../user.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.css'],
})
export class HomePage {
  private u ='1'
  private all
  private u1 = {username: undefined}
  private u2 = {username: undefined}
  private u3 = {username: undefined}

  constructor(private users:UserService){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.u3 = this.users.findByUsername(this.u)
    this.users.userList.subscribe( (data) => {
      this.all = data
      this.u1 = this.users.findByUsername(this.u);
      this.u2 = data[1]
    });
  }
}
```

user.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable, BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  public userList : BehaviorSubject<any[]> = new BehaviorSubject([
    { username: '1'}, {username: '2'}]);

  constructor() {}

  findByUsername(username: string) {
    return this.userList.value.find(each => each.username === username);
  }

}
```

home.page.html

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label position="floating">username</ion-label>
    <ion-input
    name="username"
    type="text"
      [(ngModel)]="u1.username"
      required
    ></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <p *ngFor="let each of all; let i = index">u{{i +1}}: {{each.username}}</p>
  <p>u3: {{u3.username}}</p>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`u1` and `u3` are two references to the same object. So if you modify `u1`, you also modify `u3`: they're the same object:

```
this.u3 = this.users.findByUsername(this.u)
// so u3 is the element from the list which has this.u as its name

this.u1 = this.users.findByUsername(this.u);
// so u1 is also the element from the list which has this.u as its name
```

Comment: `u1` is a reference, hence `NgModel` is entangled with the reference, not `u1` itself, right?

Comment: I have no idea of what you mean by "being entangled". `[(ngModel)]="u1.username"` means: whenever you enter something in that input field, call `u1.username = 'the-entered-value'`. So that will modify the username property of the objected referenced by u1. And since u3 references the same object, `u3.username` will have the same value as `u1.username`.

Comment: Just like when you do `const u1 = {username: ''}; const u3 = u1; u1.username = 'hello'; console.log(u3.username);`, that will print 'hello'.

Comment: By entangled I meant two-way data binding

Comment: I expected : `[(ngModel)]="u1.username"` to change its value because the two-way data binding, but not `u3` since does not have any NgModel `<p>u3: {{u3.username}}</p>`

Comment: I repeat: u1 and u3 reference the exact same object. So if you modify the object referenced by u1, you also modify the object referenced by u3. Angular won't magically create a copy of the object and assign it to u1 before modifying it. If you want that, do it yourself. If you give the same piece of paper to two people and one writes something on it, then the other psersons's piece of paper will have something written on it: they both use the same piece of paper. Same here.

Comment: Assume nothing. I don't expect magic from Angular. I was trying to understand something that I clearly don't and the reason behind it. Thanks for the paper analogy , though

Answer (score 0):

For those struggling with the 'reference to objects' topic, check this playground:https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-4-observables-playground

When the home.page loads, `u3` loads a reference to an specific object(**obj1**) of that concrete array(**arr1**), so does `u1`, but with a subscription for new incoming arrays.

As soon as you hit the 'Refresh Array' button, `u3` will point to a location in memory(**obj1** inside **arr1**) that is no longer part of the new subscription emitted array(**obj01** inside **arr2**) hence it will not upload its value when you change it in the input field, but `u1` will update its reference to the object inside the new emitted array since it reassigns inside the subscription.

Thanks to JB Nizet